# Archlinux | undefined referencies with caffe-lstm build

Tags: makefile, caffe, lstm

I installed caffe without any problem but when i'm trying to build caffe-lstm i have next issues:

```
[ 86%] Linking CXX executable train_net
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTget_dataset_ndims'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_int'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTfind_dataset'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Batch<double>*>::pop(std::string const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_double'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_int'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_float'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::NameOfEnum(google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const*, int)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_float'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTget_dataset_info'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_string'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Batch<float>*>::pop(std::string const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_double'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/test_net.dir/build.make:127: tools/test_net] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:510: tools/CMakeFiles/test_net.dir/all] Error 2
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTget_dataset_ndims'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_int'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTfind_dataset'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Batch<double>*>::pop(std::string const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_double'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_int'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_float'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::NameOfEnum(google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const*, int)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_float'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTget_dataset_info'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_string'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Batch<float>*>::pop(std::string const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_double'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/train_net.dir/build.make:127: tools/train_net] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:548: tools/CMakeFiles/train_net.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from /usr/include/boost/type_traits/ice.hpp:15:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/def_helper.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:18,
                 from /home/standnail/Git/caffe-lstm/tools/caffe.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/ice_or.hpp:17:71: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (ice_or.hpp) is deprecated
 # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (ice_or.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/type_traits/ice.hpp:16:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/def_helper.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:18,
                 from /home/standnail/Git/caffe-lstm/tools/caffe.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp:18:72: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (ice_and.hpp) is deprecated
 # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (ice_and.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/type_traits/ice.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/def_helper.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:18,
                 from /home/standnail/Git/caffe-lstm/tools/caffe.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp:17:72: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (ice_not.hpp) is deprecated
 # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (ice_not.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/type_traits/ice.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/def_helper.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/class.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:18,
                 from /home/standnail/Git/caffe-lstm/tools/caffe.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp:17:71: note: #pragma message: NOTE: Use of this header (ice_eq.hpp) is deprecated
 # pragma message("NOTE: Use of this header (ice_eq.hpp) is deprecated")
                                                                       ^
[ 86%] Linking CXX executable caffe
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTget_dataset_ndims'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_int'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTfind_dataset'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Batch<double>*>::pop(std::string const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_double'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_int'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_float'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::NameOfEnum(google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const*, int)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_float'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTget_dataset_info'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_string'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Batch<float>*>::pop(std::string const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTread_dataset_double'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `H5LTmake_dataset_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/build.make:127: tools/caffe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:472: tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
```

Working on archlinux and all packages are installed. I set blas to openblas like

> cmake -DBLAS=open ../caffe-lstm/

and fixed in make.config file

> BLAS := open

Build on **gcc4.9.3** and **g++5.4.0**

Comment: Either you have not installed or build a dependency or the CMake script is broken. Please ask one of the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in protobuf and cuda. I installed protobuf2.5 and cuda8 after this i have no issues.

Tips:
Protobuf should be downloaded from git or sourceforge and compile it. Same thing with cuda. Caffe doesn't like downloaded libs from repositories.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem trying to compile [caffe-fast-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn), however I noticed that I had no problem compiling the official caffe version with the same config (protobuf and cuda version). So comparing both version I corrected the issue by adding a line to the CAFFE_ROOT/cmake/Dependencies.cmake :

```
# ---[ HDF5
find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS HL REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${HDF5_HL_INCLUDE_DIR})
list(APPEND Caffe_LINKER_LIBS ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
list(APPEND Caffe_LINKER_LIBS ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES}) #added
```

This problem have been corrected in the current caffe version, however you may still find it if you try to compile forks based on older versions..

Ps : I build using cmake.

Comment: This solution fixed the same problem which occurred when building NVCaffe (NVIDIA Caffe) on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Same here: was able to build NVCaffe with the above fix